# awk/sed: Insert file content before last line of specific block number

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, freebsd

Given are two files, the first is an Apache config file:

```
$ cat vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
foobar 2
    barfoo 1
 foobar 1
   barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
```

And the second file contains lines that should be added to the end of one (variable) specific VirtualHost block:

```
$ cat inserted.txt
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
```

The result should look like this:

```
$ cat vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
foobar 2
    barfoo 1
 foobar 1
   barfoo 2
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried it with some variations of the following sed but that didn't do the trick:

```
$ sed -e '/^<VirtualHost/{:a;n;/^<\/VirtualHost/\!ba;r inserted.txt' -e '}' vhosts-ssl.conf
```

I can't figure out how to select only the one VirtualHost block i need to insert the file to and since i've to use FreeBSD sed (or awk) i also get this error with previous sed command:

```
$ sed -e '/^<VirtualHost/{:a;n;/^<\/VirtualHost/\!ba;r inserted.txt' -e '}' vhosts-ssl.conf
sed: 2: "}
": unused label 'a;n;/^<\/VirtualHost/!ba;r inserted.txt'
```

With GNU sed i get the this output:

```
$ gsed -e '/^<VirtualHost/{:a;n;/^<\/VirtualHost/\!ba;r inserted.txt' -e '}' vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2


<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
foobar 2
    barfoo 1
 foobar 1
   barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2

<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2


<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
```

As i would like to understand my mistakes and lern from them, i would prefer answers with some explanation and maybe even some links to rtfm, thanks.

Added 2016-10-16

Pseudocode:

```
if BLOCK begins with /^<VirtualHost/
    and ends with /^<\/VirtualHost/
        and is the ${n-th} BLOCK
            in FILE_1
then insert content of FILE_2
    before last line of ${n-th} BLOCK
        without touching rest of FILE_1
endif
save modified FILE_1
```

The ${n-th} is gathered by:

```
$ httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS | \
    grep -i "${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN}" | \
    awk '/^[^\ ]*:443[\ ]*/ {print $3}' | \
    sed -e 's|(\(.*\))|\1|' | \
    cut -d: -f2
```

Output is a the number of the BLOCK i want to extend by FILE_2

And please only non-GNU versions as i'm on FreeBSD, thanks.

Comment: I added some pseudocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

requires multi-char record separator, supported by `gawk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{insert=$0; next} 
  {print $0 (FNR==2?insert:"") RT}' RS='^$' insert.file RS="</VirtualHost>" file
```

read the first file in complete and assign to the variable insert, while iterating the second file at the end of second record print the variable after the record contents.

Another version for plain `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{insert=insert?insert ORS $0:$0; next} 
       /<\/VirtualHost>/ && ++c==2{print insert} 1' insert.file file
```

Comment: @karakfa...Last time I saw your rep you had 1,500 which was a year ago..you==awkist!...nice answer..lol

Comment: OK, works exactly as i need it, but as you said only with gawk.

Comment: I need this for FreeBSD awk.

Comment: The second version does it. Now i've to read a bit more about awk, seems to be more powerful than sed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU `sed` (and BusyBox `sed`)  the file/label/text after the `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, and `:` commands can be delimited by a semicolon, while in other versions of `sed` the file/label/text may only be delimited by a newline.

That behavior means that instead of defining the label `a`, the first string defines the label
`a;n;/^<\/VirtualHost/\!ba;r inserted.txt`, and like the separate use of `-e` for the closing brace, the script must be separated after both the label and the branch.
(also, the `!` must not be escaped)

```
sed -e '/^<VirtualHost/{:a' -e 'n;/^<\/VirtualHost/!ba' \
    -e 'r inserted.txt' -e '}' vhosts-ssl.conf
```

Alternatively, the script can span multiple lines:

```
sed '/^<VirtualHost/ {
        :a
        n
        /^<\/VirtualHost/!ba
        r inserted.txt
}' vhosts-ssl.conf
```

Note that this splitting may not work in situations where the newline must be escaped; for example, when using the `a`, `c`, and `i` commands.

Comment: Thank for the explanation of the label behaviour differences.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat f1.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
INSERT HERE
line 4
line 5
$ cat f2.txt
INSERTED LINE 1
INSERTED LINE 2
```

You can do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{fc=""} FNR==NR{fc=fc $0 "\n";next} /^INSERT HERE/{printf "%s", fc; next} 1' f2.txt f1.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
INSERTED LINE 1
INSERTED LINE 2
line 4
line 5
```

Comment: Nice, but i don't have anything i can use as "INSERT HERE", see my posted vhosts-ssl.conf and the newly added pseudocode.