# awk: delete lines in specific block of text

Tags: shell, unix, awk, freebsd

This time i search for an extended version of the second awk-oneliner from the accepted answer to my [question 40066030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066030/), so please have a look there first, thanks.

This awk has to be extended so i can delete all lines containing the word foobar from the same block number (num) before i insert the file inserted.txt into it:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v num=2 'NR==FNR{ins=ins?ins ORS $0:$0; next} /<\/VirtualHost>/ && ++c==num{print ins} 1' inserted.txt vhosts-ssl.conf
```

Output of previous awk:

```
$ cat vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
foobar 2
    barfoo 1
 foobar 1
   barfoo 2
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
```

Output i need to get:

```
$ cat vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
    barfoo 1
   barfoo 2
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
```

Original input data for reference:

```
$ cat inserted.txt
inserted line 1
 inserted line 2
$ cat vhosts-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 1
  foobar 1
  foobar 2
  barfoo 1
  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  vhost 2
foobar 2
    barfoo 1
 foobar 1
   barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
vhost 3
  foobar 1

   barfoo 1
 foobar 2

  barfoo 2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    vhost 4
 foobar 1
   foobar 2

  barfoo 1
barfoo 2

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to insert various seach&replace and delete snippets right before the print, but that didn't work (stupid me) :( Something like that:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v num=2 'NR==FNR{ins=ins?ins ORS $0:$0; next} /<\/VirtualHost>/ && ++c==num{!/foobar/ print ins} 1' inserted.txt vhosts-ssl.conf
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the script slightly as such

```
$ awk -v num=2     'NR==FNR{ins=ins?ins ORS $0:$0; next} 
   /<VirtualHost/&&++c==num{p=1} 
       p&&/<\/VirtualHost>/{print ins; p=0} 
              !p||!/foobar/' insert.file orig.file
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks again. I'm going to buy a book about awk, realy great tool.